# How to disable ssl for certain folders of ASP.NET 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ssl, .net-4.0, https

I want to disable SSL in some folders of a ASP.Net 4 web application.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'ASP.Net 4' way of doing this that springs to mind. You would have to implement this functionality by hand.

Without knowing what the specifics of your web app are it is hard to offer examples.
For instance, if you are using asp.net mvc, you could have the controller that pertains to a 'folder' within your app check for SSL (by examining the port number of the originating request for instance) and having it redirect to the equivalent action in a non-SSL version of the site. You would, however, lose any session context (only a concern if you are using session).

ASP.Net webforms would probably be a little trickier to configure with this behaviour.

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms would probably rely on the web.config for the subfolder.